# Extending visual studio debugger

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I have linked list containing few tens of objects like this:

```
struct Item {
    Item * next;
    const char * name;
    ....
};
```

When I want to see in debugger in visual studio what item list holds, I need to hover/click on next many times to expand whole list until I hit nullptr. This is slow, error-prone (hand slips and I can start all over again) and not very organized.

Is there any scripting for VS2015 debugger available in which I could iterate whole list and just dump the name into console or whatever?

EDIT: I found about concord extensibility api ( https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/10/02/announcing-visual-studio-debug-engine-extensibility-samples/ ) but it seems rather complex.

This is supposed to be in-house tool, so speed/ease of development is more important than robustness and/or easy of deployment.

Answer (score 0):

If the data set you are working with is small, I would go with the tried and true method of std::cout.

Or just dump the contents of the list into a file and put a break point after that file is written to so you can check its contents before the program continues.

Comment: The codebase is huge, I can't just stick dumping into std::cout all over the place. And even incremental compilation takes around 15 minutes. So I need something I can trigger on demand while stepping through the code with debugger..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. Insert a Tracepoint (Right mouse button> Breakpoint >Insert Tracepoint) and READ CAREFULLY to whole text of that window. Then you will know HOW to print to the Output window WHAT you want.

Insert also a breakpoint on another line that is CONDITIONAL. Just put a normal breakpoint, then over the red ball, Right mouse button > Condition, then input

```
!next
```

Notice the `!`